# Laravel Job executed immediately in browser instead of running in a background queue

Tags: php, laravel, queue, jobs, laravel-5.8

I'm new to Laravel, and tried to create my first background task.

Used docs: https://laravel.com/docs/master/queues

Job: (ProcessDatabaseImport.php)

```
<?php

namespace App\Jobs;

use App\Contact;
use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Bus\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Log;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;

class ProcessDatabaseImport implements ShouldQueue
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithQueue, Queueable, SerializesModels;

    protected $file;

    /**
     * Create a new job instance.
     *
     * @param String $filePath
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct($filePath)
    {
        // init File object "database/data/contacts.json"
        $this->file = base_path($filePath);
    }

    /**
     * Execute the job.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function handle()
    {
       Log::info('Hello world! file: '.$this->file);
    }

    /**
     * Determine the time at which the job should timeout.
     *
     * @return \DateTime
     */
    public function retryUntil()
    {
        return now()->addSeconds(30);
    }
}
?>
```

JobController.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Jobs\ProcessDatabaseImport;
use Carbon\Carbon;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\Job;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Queue;

class JobController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Handle Queue Process
     */
    public function processQueue()
    {
        ProcessDatabaseImport::dispatch('database/data/contacts.json')->delay(now()->addMinutes(2));

        return view('home');
    }
}
```

Jobs table is created, `php artisan queue:work` is running.

Now, when i go to the controller action in my browser, the code in "handle()" is exectuted twice, directly:

Log:

```
[2019-07-14 13:39:17] local.INFO: Hello world! file: B:\hellodialog\sollicitatieopdracht\database/data/contacts.json  
[2019-07-14 13:39:18] local.INFO: Hello world! file: B:\hellodialog\sollicitatieopdracht\database/data/contacts.json
```

The database table for jobs is always empty.

In my .env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
QUEUE_CONNECTION=database
```

queue.php config file:

```
return [


    'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'database'),

    'connections' => [

        'sync' => [
            'driver' => 'sync',
        ],

        'database' => [
            'driver' => 'database',
            'table' => 'jobs',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
        ],

        'beanstalkd' => [
            'driver' => 'beanstalkd',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'queue' => 'default',
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => 0,
        ],

        'sqs' => [
            'driver' => 'sqs',
            'key' => env('AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID'),
            'secret' => env('AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY'),
            'prefix' => env('SQS_PREFIX', 'https://sqs.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/your-account-id'),
            'queue' => env('SQS_QUEUE', 'your-queue-name'),
            'region' => env('AWS_DEFAULT_REGION', 'us-east-1'),
        ],

        'redis' => [
            'driver' => 'redis',
            'connection' => 'default',
            'queue' => env('REDIS_QUEUE', 'default'),
            'retry_after' => 90,
            'block_for' => null,
        ],

    ],

    'failed' => [
        'database' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
        'table' => 'failed_jobs',
    ],
```

Is something missing?

**Update:** The job is added to the queue when I changed the default in queue.php

The job is now added twice to the database. I run this script by visiting the URL in my browser.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like you have two questions.

**Running immediately in the browser**

As for running immediately, this could happen if Laravel is still using the default `sync` driver. Check your `/config/queue.php` file and make sure the `env()` property is being used.  Sync is the default fallback if no queue driver is set in your `.env` file, but you could also change this if you want.

```php
'default' => env('QUEUE_CONNECTION', 'sync'),
```

If everything looks okay, try running `php artisan config:clear` to empty the config cache.  It's possible that the default `sync` driver is still cached.

Alternatively, you can try explicitly defining the connection you wish to use.

```php
ProcessDatabaseImport::dispatch('database/data/contacts.json')
    ->onConnection('database')
    ->delay(now()->addMinutes(2));
```

**Running twice**

I'm not sure about this, but what happens if you remove the `retryUntil()` method from the Job?

Also, I found a similar issue in another thread, but I don't know if it's related.
[Queued Laravel queued job runs twice after upgrading to Laravel 5.4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47148286/queued-laravel-queued-job-runs-twice-after-upgrading-to-laravel-5-4)

If this doesn't help, we might need more information about how you are initiating the job. Are you simply visiting a URL, or is it possible that the mechanism to call this route could be running twice (e.g., via Ajax)?

And you might add the applicable `/config/queue.php` configuration to your question, as there is some indication from the thread mentioned above that your `retry` and `timeout` times may come into play.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. changing the 'default' line in queue.php to use the database connection did the trick. I will add the queue.php to my question. It's still being triggered twice when i visit the URL in my browser.

Comment: In addition to my previous comment: I removed the retryUntil() function for this.

Comment: Ha, was just about to ask.  How are you running the queue worker — did you set up supervisor, are you starting it manually from the CLI, is it being triggered by the scheduler?

Comment: Actually, I guess that shouldn't matter since dispatching happens first, just trying to think it all through.

Comment: I'm running it manually on my localhost (windows machine) with the CLI

Comment: Are you running any debugging tools?  Is it possible those tools or a browser extension could be processing the request twice?

Comment: Wow, didn't expect this. It is indeed a browser-related (Google Chrome) issue. Opening the URL in Microsoft Edge does add only 1 job to the queue, once.

Comment: Nice, glad I could help.